# Failed to install MongoDB in Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: mongodb, server, ubuntu-16.04, systemctl

I want to install mongodb in a new ubuntu 16.04x64 server.

I did first

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

and

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/2.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-2.0.list
```

Then, I realised that it did not work well, so i wanted to totally follow [this thread](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04).

However, it did not work, the log is [here](https://pastebin.com/JZ97Sww1).

`mongod --version` returned

```
mongod --version
db version v3.2.18
git version: 4c1bae566c0c00f996a2feb16febf84936ecaf6f
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1404
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

And `mongod` returned

```
2018-01-20T05:18:51.736+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6998 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=iZm5edsu6v77zfb40qfbicZ
2018-01-20T05:18:51.736+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.18
2018-01-20T05:18:51.736+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 4c1bae566c0c00f996a2feb16febf84936ecaf6f
2018-01-20T05:18:51.736+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2018-01-20T05:18:51.736+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-01-20T05:18:51.736+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-01-20T05:18:51.736+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-01-20T05:18:51.736+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2018-01-20T05:18:51.736+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-01-20T05:18:51.736+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-01-20T05:18:51.736+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2018-01-20T05:18:51.758+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2018-01-20T05:18:51.758+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Additionally, how to remove `3.0 multiverse` and `2.0 multiverse` from the update list?

PS: I don't understand the difference between the above approach and a simple `sudo apt-get install mongodb` like [here](http://knowledgebasement.com/how-to-launch-a-mean-site-on-ubuntu-16-04-server/).

Comment: Try again, with 3.6 version, by using [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly It has the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

as you can see Data directory /data/db not found., terminating

simply specify dbpath by

```
mongod --dbpath <desired location for example ./data/db>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just creating the directory if you go with the defaults:

`sudo mkdir -p /data/db`

Comment: @SoftTimur did you get a different error ? Different to  "Data directory /data/db not found"